# WPF MVVM bind Hyperlink RequestNavigate to View model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, hyperlink

On WPF form I have a hyperlink that when clicked is supposed aggregate some data in database before redirecting to internal web page.

Currently XAML looks following:

```
<Hyperlink RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate" IsEnabled="{Binding CanTakePayment}">
  Launch Payments Portal
</Hyperlink>
```

to do the db stuff `Hyperlink_RequestNavigate` method is used, that resides in `View.xaml.cs`

It looks something like:

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    var transactionReference = GetToken(100M, "13215", "product");
    var url = string.Format("{0}New?transactionReference={1}", Settings.Default.PaymentUrlWebsite, transactionReference);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

I don't like this mechanism being here and would prefer to move it to View model.

What I tried to do is add to ViewModel property

```
public ICommand NavigateToTakePayment       
{
    get { return _navigateToTakePayment; }
    set { _navigateToTakePayment = value; }
}
```

and in XAML change binding to

```
<Hyperlink RequestNavigate="{Binding Path=NavigateToTakePayment}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanTakePayment}"> 
   Launch Payments Portal
</Hyperlink>
```

but it started giving me cast exceptions.

**What is most appropriate way to move this mechanism from View to ViewModel?**

Comment: Use `Command` instead of `RequestNavigate`. RequestNavigate is an event handler and it will expect code behind implementation, while command will expect Binding.

Comment: @XAMlMAX If I use command it runs fine and opens window without errors, but when I click on link nothing happens, it doesn't jump into setter.

Comment: How do you initialize your `NavigateToTakePayment` command? The setter is only used when initialised, the UI will call the `getter` as it needs to call `Execute` method on your Command. Hope this makes sense if not I will post an answer to aid my comments.

Comment: I am using backing fields that are nulls when initializing, do you think this is what's causing the issue of getter not being called on click?

Comment: Yes. I use `RelayCommand` for my `WPF` app. You need to initialize it in your Constructor and then the UI will call the backing fileds `Execute(object parameter)` method.

Comment: @XAMlMAX this did it, Instead of calling setter as one would expect it calls  `public void Execute(object parameter)` of the implementation of `ICommand` that is set to backing property. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem with your app is that the `ICommand` is not initialized before use.
I have a Command implementation like so:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        Predicate<object> _canExecute;
        Action<object> _execute;
        bool _defaultBehaviourForCanExecute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, bool defaultBehaviourForCanExecute = true, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        {
            _canExecute = canExecute;
            _execute = execute;
            _defaultBehaviourForCanExecute = defaultBehaviourForCanExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_canExecute != null)
            {
                Logger.LogInformation("Evaluating can execute method for " + _canExecute.Method.DeclaringType + "->"+_canExecute.Method.Name);
                return _canExecute.Invoke(parameter);
            }
            return _defaultBehaviourForCanExecute;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("Executing command method for " + _execute.Method.DeclaringType + "->" + _execute.Method.Name);
            _execute.Invoke(parameter);
            RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```

Now this is being initialized in my `ViewModel` like so:

```
NavigateToTakePayment = new RelayCommand(navigateToTakePayment CommandMethod);//it also can take canExecute method if you need a condition before executing.
```

then in your xaml you use it like this:

```
<Hyperlink RequestNavigate="{Binding Path=NavigateToTakePayment}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanTakePayment}">
    Launch Payments Portal
</Hyperlink>
```

BTW: when you Hyperlink needs to be disabled implement a `canexecute` method
and then it will be done automatically. If you need more info I will update my answer.
Happy coding

Answer (score 9):

`HyperLink` is a bit of a problem child. It does not support command binding.

It's possible to shoehorn support for command binding into it with an attached property, but it's easier to just modify a button to do the same thing.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="HyperlinkStyledButton">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <TextBlock Foreground="DodgerBlue"
                   Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                   TextDecorations="Underline" 
                   Cursor="Hand" />
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then use the hyperlink like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding OpenHttpLinkCommand}" Content="www.google.com" 
        Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkStyledButton}" ToolTip="Some custom tooltip"/>
```

Assuming that standard MVVM binding is working correctly:

In the ViewModel:

```
public ICommand OpenHttpLinkCommand { get; }
```

In the ViewModel constructor:

```
this.OpenHttpLinkCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.OnOpenHttpLinkCommand);
```

And the command to open the browser with a link:

```
private void OnOpenHttpLinkCommand()
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com/");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // TODO: Error.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Contango - this worked perfectly for me.

Comment: See my post elsewhere in this thread for how `Hyperlink` can be made to support command binding.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but for those still coming across it like me, `Hyperlink` does support `ICommandBinding`, but you need a derived class to do so:

```cs
using System.Windows.Documents;

public class HyperlinkCommander : Hyperlink
{
    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        Command.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

Then in your xaml use it just like you would when binding a `Button` to your *ICommand* in your ViewModel, in this case called *HyperlinkClickerCommand*.  Something like this:

```xml
<localControls:HyperlinkCommander Command="{Binding HyperlinkClickerCommand}" >
    Click me!
</localControls:HyperlinkCommander>
```

With something like this near the top of your xaml:

```xml
<Window
    ... 
    xmlns:localControls="clr-namespace:TestProject.Controls"
    ...
>
```

Where `HyperlinkClickerCommand` is your command in your ViewModel that you are binding to.  Your hyperlink as above will trigger the *Execute* of the bound command, and honour the *CanExecute* of it.